# Draw circles around points belonging to a factor level in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, anomaly-detection

A previous post describes how to draw red circles around points which exceed a given value in ggplot. I would like to do the same for anomaly detection results, but instead have the circles drawn around points belonging to a given factor level.

How could I change this code to allow circles to be drawn around a given factor level?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data=mtcars[mtcars$mpg>30,],
             pch=21, fill=NA, size=4, colour="red", stroke=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that the "factor level" you are interested in is the value `10.4` for `mtcars$mpg`. `mtcars$mpg` is a numerical vector, so you first have to convert it into a factor.

```
mtcars$mpg <- as.factor(mtcars$mpg)
```

Then you can use the same code you used previously for values greater than a limit, except that this time the condition is to belong to the factor level `10.4`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
geom_point() +
  geom_point(data=mtcars[mtcars$mpg %in% 10.4, ],
             pch=21, fill=NA, size=4, colour="red", stroke=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

Note that the conversion of `mtcars$mpg` to factor is not necessary and that the code will run on the numerical vector in the same way. I converted it since your question was about "factor level".

Note also that if you are not dealing with factor levels but simply with values matching a certain number, you can use:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data=mtcars[mtcars$mpg == 10.4, ],
             pch=21, fill=NA, size=4, colour="red", stroke=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

since you are now only testing for equality and not for appartenance.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is to first plot all points and then plot only the circles for the data reduced to the factor levels you want to highlight. Does this solve your problem?

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data=iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point(data=iris[iris$Species %in% c("setosa"),], aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width),
                 pch=21, fill=NA, size=4, colour="red", stroke=1) +
      theme_bw()
```

Please note that I changed the dataset, as I needed a factor in the data to show you how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to use the above methods to highlight a subset of points with a factored axis. Unfortunately, the inclusion of the second subset `geom_point` call seemed to reorder the axis. I was able to avoid this problem by using the [gghighlight](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html) package.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, color = as.factor(carb))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  gghighlight(carb == 2, use_direct_label = FALSE, unhighlighted_colour = NULL) +
  geom_point(pch=21, fill=NA, size=4, colour="black", stroke=0.5)
```